# In RhodeCode, is it possible to index gists for search?

Tags: rhodecode

I'd like to see gist contents included in my search results.

I've examined the configuration options and googled the topic but could not find any way to include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gist are not yet indexed by Whoosh, but it's a good idea to add this for public gists. Private must remain un-indexed since the URL is the ACL in their case and search would leak the content. We have indexer improvements on our TODO lists for 2014. I'll make sure we discuss the GIST indexing.